# Executefunction from Ribbon command in officejs

Tags: office-js

Trying to apply autofitcolumns for the excel cells after binding data into excel using ribbon command with Execute Function. Whenever initial trigger of execute from ribbon command excel not getting aligned but in subsequent click event only excel cells aligned with autocolumn.

Applied `range.getrange().format.autofitcolumns()` after data bind to excel using Excel.run promise in typescript.

```
function Execute(event)
{
binddata();
event.completed
}

async function binddata()
{
await Excel.run(async context =>{
..data bind logic here
range.getrange().format.autofitcolumns();
return context.sync();
})
}
```

**Expected result** : On every click from ribbon command event once execute method called then data should bind in Excel with autocolumn alignment.

**Actual result** : Once triggering execute event from ribbon command first time data binding in excel not getting aligned. But subsequent click event only previously binded data getting aligned. So every current event it is not getting aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `await` in front of the line `binddata()`.

Comment: I tried putting await but still same issue. Any other thought?

Comment: Hi Rick, Any help on this.

Comment: Hi Team, Any other solutions since i stucked past two days.

Comment: Tried below format also but not working as expected.                                    function Execute(event)
{
binddata();
event.completed
}

function binddata()
{
Excel.run(context =>{
..data bind logic here
range.getrange().format.autofitcolumns();
return context.sync();
})
}